# Getting "Auth failed" for linux connection through Jsch, for the below code

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, jsch

I'm receiving following exception:

> "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail"

for the below code, while connecting to Linux server. Even though the credentials which i have provided is valid

```
String host="hostname";
String user="usename";
String password="password";
String command="ksh samplePass";
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword(password);
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please give us a little more information with regards to your question - what have you tried, what works, what hasn't, etc. If you have time, please take a look at the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through our help pages (https://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out how to ask good questions and get good answers. I hope you enjoy your stay!

Comment: Are you able to connect with any standalone SSH/SFTP client? Show us its log file!